# Edit Atom's autocompete

Tags: html, meteor, attributes, atom-editor

Is there a way of editing Atom's auto-complete so that it auto completes with a different attribute?

Currently I can type 'template' and it auto completes to

```
<template id=""></template>
```

which I would prefer auto completed to

```
<template name=""></template>
```

if there is a file somewhere maybe I could edit?

Comment: Do you use any package or is it native behaviour?

Comment: I use emmet but to edit the native behavior would be suitable to

Comment: are you using https://github.com/awatson1978/meteor-api?

Comment: I am, I find no change - but it does do highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to define your own [snippet](https://github.com/atom/snippets):
`File` > `Open your snippets`

Add the following:

```
'.source.js':
  'tmpl':
    'prefix': 'Template Trigger'
    'body': '<template name=""></template>'
```

You will probably want to [customize the scope](https://github.com/atom/snippets#determining-the-correct-scope-for-a-snippet) for your requirements.

Comment: Cheers! Thanks - I will give that a go.